# GRPC Java service in cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-run, grpc-java

I am new to GRPC and Cloud Run.
I have written a very simple grpc java service. The same service works fine when I run them locally.
However, when I deploy to cloud run,I am not able to call the grpc server.
The grpc service is listening on port $PORT(8080) as specified in the document.

The server code is

```
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port).addService(this).build();
            server.start();
```

The following are the cloud run configurations
Ingress Control : All (Allow direct access to your service from the internet)
Enabled Use HTTP/2 end-to-end
Authentication : Allow unauthenticated invocations

The java client is connected like this

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(grpcHost, grpcPort).usePlaintext().build();
SimpleGrpcServiceBlockingStub grpcStub = SimpleGrpcServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

The grpcHost is xxxxx.a.run.app (without https) and the grpcPort is 8080

What am I mising here ? Any suggestions.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Srinivasan

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: xx.a.run.app/2001:4860:4802:32:0:0:0:35:8080

Comment: Is your client trying to connect on port 8080? Your client should connect on port 443 (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/grpc#connect).

Comment: If I need to connect with port 443, does that mean, I need to enable ssl certification as well ?

Comment: @BenK - Tried with port 443, still getting the same error connection timed out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Hi,

The issue is that the client should listen to port 443 with SSL

The following code change helped me to connect with GRPC server in cloud run

```
SslContext sslCtxt = GrpcSslContexts.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();

ManagedChannel channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(utilGrpcHost, utilGrpcPort)

.sslContext(sslCtxt).build();
```